# Sending Push-Notifications to PWA on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, spring-boot, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a website for a Dog sports-club in which I am a member and wanted to be as user-friendly as possible and made this website a PWA.
My tech-stack:
Angular 16, which was used to create the PWA

Spring-Boot >3

MongoDB

On Android everything is working fine, but on IOS the Push-Notifications are not shown. I am using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

as my way to provide Push-Notifications to the android phones.
I store the subscriptions in my DB and it is something like this:
https://web.push.apple.com/xxxxxx with the corresponding p256dh and auth

I have read that Safari did not support Push-Notifications until march 2023 (version 16.4).
I also read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_safari_and_other_browsers)

> You don’t need to join the Apple Developer Program to send web push notifications.

But somehow the Push-Notifications are not shown on the Apple-Devices. The device used for "testing" also has enabled the "Push-API" and "Notifications" in the experimental settings ([as read here](https://taoshu.in/web/push-on-ios.html))

What am I missing? Can someone provide me a way to make it work, so everyone in the club can recieve the informations and the website flourishes.

One additional information: I do not have any Apple-Product. And I am not planning on buying one just for the development-process. If anyone could show me a way how I could test this on my non-ios-systems, i would be very grateful.

It was tried to reinstall the PWA -> no success
I did not try to use any other java implementation because I am completely confused whether I need a certificate (that I get from registering my app on apple, which would need a developer-account) or not since the guideline I linked earlier said it was not neccessary.

**Edit1**
I know that the bouncycastle-dependency does not send to APNS. Is it still neccessary? I thought after reading that it is obsolete from now on.
If this is still needed I guess I still need a certificate so I can use something like this:
[Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy) to send to APNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
Since I am using the mentioned library I followed all those guides, that were using it too.

But none used the "subject" paramter of the constructor of the pushservice.
All used new Pushservice(publickey,privatekey), but it is necessary to provide the subject as well (see [webpush-documentation](https://web.dev/push-notifications-web-push-protocol/)). Like this: ew PushService(publicKey, privateKey,subject).

As I said in the question: chrome/google worked with that, but mozilla + apple (using IOS>16.4, with experimental features) needed this subject for the JWT, since I am using VAPID-Keys.